# Sort List<DateTime> Descending

Tags: c#, sorting, lambda

In c# (3.0 or 3.5, so we can use lambdas), is there an elegant way of sorting a list of dates in descending order? I know I can do a straight sort and then reverse the whole thing,

```
docs.Sort((x, y) => x.StoredDate.CompareTo(y.StoredDate));
docs.Reverse();
```

but is there a lambda expression to do it one step?

In the above example, StoredDate is a property typed as a DateTime.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

Though it's untested...

```
docs.Sort((x, y) => y.StoredDate.CompareTo(x.StoredDate));
```

should be the opposite of what you originally had.

Comment: Can you explain more about what is happening with the list and why ?

Comment: OP was comparing x to y and then reversing; logically, this is the same as comparing y to x and leaving in that order.

Answer (score 67):

What's wrong with:

```
docs.OrderByDescending(d => d.StoredDate);
```

Comment: Note that this creates a new ordered list rather than modifying the list in place. Granted, the performance loss is negligible.

Comment: Adding to what Cavyn said, this will always returns list of IOrderedEnumerable<T> which would need to be converted back to generic list using .ToList<T>().

Answer (score 22):

```
docs.Sort((x, y) => y.StoredDate.CompareTo(x.StoredDate));
```

Should do what you're looking for.

Comment: Can you explain more about what is happening with the list and why ?

Answer (score 8):

```
docs.Sort((x, y) => -x.StoredDate.CompareTo(y.StoredDate));
```

Note the minus sign.