# C# - How to sort ListBox containing times

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have a `ListBox`, it contains times. I have set the display format of the time string as shown in the screenshot.

How can I sort the times morning to evening, for example:

```
10:20:23 AM
11:56:65 AM
01:12:68 PM
```

[image]

Comment: You have to use 24 hours format to be able to sort string representation of time, or move `AM`/`PM` part in front of numbers (this way they can be alphabetically sorted too). Otherwise, you have to sort time by using underlying data (not converted to string yet), by using which you can sort `ListBox` manually (like in the answers below).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like :

For sorting based on dates:

```
datesList.Sort((x, y) => x.StoredDate.CompareTo(y.StoredDate));
```

OR

For sorting on time of day:

```
var list = dateList.OrderBy(x => x.TimeOfDay).ToList();
```

Source: [Sort DateTime List by Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18070517/sort-datetime-list-by-time)
 & [Sort List<DateTime> Descending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244219/sort-listdatetime-descending)

Answer (score 1):

You must be using a List or any collection to bind the ListBox. Sort the List or collection by the column you are binding.

```
lstDates.OrderByAscending(x => x.Date)
```

Comment: What you mean by lstDate. What is this?

Comment: How do you populate the ListBox?

Comment: i am using array named listdate